# How to make any app popup/drop-down on screen (like yakuake)

Tags: shortcut-keys, window, window-manager, yakuake

I love the [Yakuake](https://apps.kde.org/yakuake/) console: with a single key (F12 I believe), you get a terminal that drops-down on top of any app you are currently using. Another tap on that key, the terminal goes away, and can be called again any time (with session preserved). I find it way easier than having to go through alt+tab to find the console I opened 10 minutes ago, possibly on another desktop.

I would like to know if it is possible to get a similar behaviour with any other app? For example, I would like the system monitor to pop up on screen with a shortcut, and disappear with the same shortcut. I don't want the app to be closed each time, I just want it hidden, ready to be brought back to the foreground when I need it (without having to go through alt+tab to find it).

I managed to bring the app to the foreground with a shortcut executing `wmctrl -R 'App name'`, but I don't know how to hide the app after that using the same key.

Distro used : Kubuntu 22.04

Comment: [edit] your question with the version/distro of Ubuntu

Comment: Oops sorry! Done